# App runs fine in Lollipop but crashes in KitKat

Tags: android

I developed an app in Android, which runs fine in lollipop device, but crash in KitKat device. Please help me for find the solution.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '21.1.1'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.itsoft37.kitkat"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.1.0'
}
```

The error shows unfortunately stopped on device.

Answer (score 0):

when i change the api version..

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 19
        buildToolsVersion '19.1.0'

        defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.itsoft37.kitkat"
    minSdkVersion 11
    targetSdkVersion 19
        }

        buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.1.0'
    }
```

This error will show..
                Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Multi dex requires Build Tools 21.0.0 / Current: 19.1

Comment: add  multiDexEnabled true in defaultconfig and try

Comment: if you still get exception means change buildToolsVersion to 21.1.2

Comment: i try it in kitkat device.so unable to saw the error log...but i find this kind of code while i debug from system to lollipop device..

Comment: 07-14 20:32:56.366 8681-8681/com.example.itsoft37.kitkat E/Zygote: accessInfo : 0
07-14 20:32:56.366 8681-8681/com.example.itsoft37.kitkat E/SELinux: [DEBUG] get_category: variable seinfo: default sensitivity: NULL, cateogry: NULL

Comment: will build tool version 21.1.2 under the kitkat or not?

Answer (score 0):

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.1.0'

    defaultConfig {
applicationId "com.example.itsoft37.kitkat"
minSdkVersion 11
targetSdkVersion 19

**multiDexEnabled true**
    }

    buildTypes {
release {
    minifyEnabled false
    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.1.0'


    **compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'**
}
```